# Different member behaviour of inner class if inner class extends outer class?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

Today I stumbled about some strange inner (non-static) class behaviour.

If I have the following classes ...

```
class B {
    String val = "old";

    void run(){
        val = "new";
        System.out.println(val);        // outputs: new
        new InnerB().printVal();        // outputs: new
    }

    private class InnerB {
        void printVal(){ System.out.println(val); }
    }
}

new B().run();
```

... everything seems to be clear. The instance of InnerB belongs to the instance of B so if it should output val it prints the already replaced value 'new'.

BUT if the inner class extends the outer class this doesn't work.

```
class B {
    String val = "old";

    void run(){
        val = "new";
        System.out.println(val);        // outputs: new
        new InnerB().printVal();        // outputs: new
        new InheritedB().printVal();    // outputs: old new
    }

    private class InnerB {
        void printVal(){ System.out.println(val); }
    }

    private class InheritedB extends B{
        void printVal(){ System.out.println(val + " "+ B.this.val); }
    }
}

new B().run(); // outputs: new new old!
```

If I have a look at the constructors I also see that a new instance of B will be created if instance of InheritedB is created.

I find this very strange... Can somebody explain why there is this difference?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't mean `InheritedB extends InnerB`?

Comment: Just for my peace of mind, please tell me you're not planning to do this in real code, that you were just messing around to see what happened.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This line:

```
new InheritedB().printVal();
```

creates a new instance of `InheritedB`, whose containing instance is the existing instance of `B` (where val is `"new"`). But at this point there are *two* `val` variables:

- The one in the existing instance of `B`
- The one in the instance of `InheritedB`, which has a separate `val` field

The value of the second variable is `"old"` because that's effectively the default value of the field.

This statement in `InheritedB`:

```
System.out.println(val + " "+ B.this.val);
```

prints out the value of `val` inherited from `B`, followed by the value of `val` in the "containing instance".

It might be simpler to think of it being refactored to:

```
public class B
{
    String val = "old";
}

public class InheritedB extends B {
    B other;

    public InheritedB(B other)
    {
        this.other = other;
    }

    void printVal() {
        System.out.println(val + " "+ other.val);
    }
}
```

Then you're basically running:

```
B original = new B();
original.val = "new":
InheritedB inherited = new InheritedB(original);
inherited.printVal();
```

Hopefully you can follow exactly what's going on there. The compiler is *roughly* performing your original code into that code.

Answer (score 9):

`val` in `InheritedB` refers to the `val` from its *base class* (`super.val`), since that's part of `this`.

If you don't inherit from the outer class, `val` refers to the scope from the outer class (`B.this.scope`).  However, since you inherit, `this` is closer in scope, and therefore hides the outer scope.

Since you never called `run()` *on the inner `this`*, `this.val` is still `old`.

---

> If I have a look at the constructors I also see that a new instance of B will be created if instance of InheritedB is created.

Yes; creating a derived class will always create an instance of its base class.  There is no way to inherit from an existing instance.

Answer (score 5):

Since `InheritedB extends B`, creating an instance of InheritedB grants it a `val` attribute, which is "old" by default for any **new** B class or subclass instance.

Here, `InheritedB`  prints **its own** `val` attribute, not the one of the enclosing B instance.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `InheritedB` there are two variables called `val`, the one of `B` and the one of `InheritedB`. Applying visibility rules gives the observed result.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is class `InnerB` does not have member `val` in it. where as class `InheritedB` extends class B and has its own copy of the `val` member.

```
void run(){

    val = "new";     //<--- modifies B's val not InheritedB's val

    System.out.println(val);        // outputs: new
    new InnerB().printVal();        // outputs: new
    new InheritedB().printVal();    // outputs: old new
}
```

In the above code block, InnerB's printVal access the container's `val` member, which value was already modified in the `run` method to value  *new*.

But the copy of val in InheritedB's object is still "**old**" value, not modified, and printVal function uses that value.